# Are there any Linux distributions which have Perl 6 as the default/only Perl version?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, perl, version

The title pretty much says it all.

In the same way that [Arch Linux has Python 3 as the built-in/main version of Python](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python), are there any Linux/Unixish distros that have done the same with Perl 6? I know that, even compared to the Python 2/3 incompatibilities, the jump from Perl 5 to 6 breaks a *lot* of code, but I'm still wondering if any distro, even a hobby-shop one, has set it as default anyway.

Comment: I don't believe there are, Perl 6 is still very slow (and while most Perl 5 stuff _should_ run under Perl 6, there are no guarantees... and why risk it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Fedora 17 and sometime ago i updated Perl to version 6 using yum. The problem is that default symbolic links still referred to previous version. I had to change the symbolic links for it to refer to new update.

Look for appropriat file in http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=rakudo-star. Then correct the symbolic links to get it working.
Remember that some perl based applications can crash after this, so evaluate how much you need perl6. You can create new/different links to perl6 if you know that you use some perl based application that still uses perl5.

Answer (score 1):

(Completely rewritten.)

I'm not aware of any.

Some key issues:

- Stock Rakudo, the "reference" Perl 6 compiler, doesn't compile Perl 5 code.
- Perl 5 is used for the build/configure systems of several key Perl 6 components.
  So any system with Perl 6 on it probably needs to also have Perl 5 on it.
  At least in the short to medium term (years).
- The current approach is to name the compiler executable 'perl6'.
  You'd have to tinker to have 'perl' invoke a Perl 6 compiler.
  And you'd still need to deal with the first two issues.

Comment: I get why people don't like Perl 6. I understand that it breaks way more Perl 5 code than Python 3 broke Python 2 code. I still would like to know if this is possible.